# CSS3 ::selection behaves differently in FF & Chrome

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm experimenting with the `::selection` pseudo-element in CSS3. In Firefox it works and looks great. My site has a dark navy blue background.

I set the selection so that it looks like this in FF.

[image]

But in chrome the same test looks like this. It seems that chrome interprets the selection as semi transparent the resultant color is nasty.

[image]

Does anyone know if it's possible to get chrome to behave the same as Firefox.

For reference here is my css:

```
p::-moz-selection { background:#FFFF7D; color:#032764; }
p::-webkit-selection { background:#FFFF7D; color:#032764; }
p::selection { background:#FFFF7D; color:#032764; }
```

Thanks

Comment: It's funny that they dropped it from the official spec yet browser vendors are doing such a fantastic job implementing it. Well, except Chrome.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For some reason Chrome forces it to be semi-transparent. However, you can get around this by setting the `background` using rgba. I have set the alpha value to be just 0.01 less than 1. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/m8End/

```
p::-moz-selection {
    background:rgba(255, 255, 125, 0.99);
    color:#032764;
}
p::-webkit-selection {
    background:rgba(255, 255, 125, 0.99);
    color:#032764;
}
p::selection {
    background:rgba(255, 255, 125, 0.99);
    color:#032764;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! at least it was a simple fix.

Comment: "For some reason" Because it's not standardized, any browser has the right to flip out ;)

Comment: @boltclock: Agreed! You just have to make sure you slap it on the wrist and tell it not to do it again!

Comment: It's weird how setting alpha to `0.999` for instance makes it do it the wrong way. Are we trying to set the value equal to `255/256`?

Comment: `&::selection, p::-webkit-selection, p::-moz-selection {background:rgba(255, 255, 125, 0.99); color:#032764;}`

Comment: @Drops nope, you need to separate them :-) Browsers ignore the whole block if there is one element of the selector they don't understand.

Comment: Just to add to  @StevenLu ’s insight, the alpha level is zero based, so we actually want **254/255**. Works in SASS: `background-color: rgba(skyblue, 254/255);`

Answer (score 9):

As [Steven Lu has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224445/css3-selection-behaves-differently-in-ff-chrome#comment18841870_7224621) in a comment to [tw16's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7224621), the opacity treshold is `255/256`.

[image: calc]

In other words, `0.996` will work but `0.997` will not.

Let's see it in action:

```css
::selection
{
  background: rgba(255, 127, 0, 0.996);
  color: white;
}

::-moz-selection
{
  background: #F80;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>The domestic cat is a small, usually furry, domesticated, and carnivorous mammal. They are often called a housecat when kept as an indoor pet, or simply a cat when there is no need to distinguish them from other felids and felines. Cats are often valued by humans for companionship.</p>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/75/300">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/300">
<p>A Melvin, Michigan woman was brutally attacked by a stray cat and shocking footage of the mauling has already gained a million views on YouTube.</p>
<p>The woman, who identified herself to reporters only as Maxx, endured the horrific attack November 30 but only recently realized it had been caught on her home surveillance camera.</p>
<p>The attack left her face swollen and infected and the cat named Buddy dead as officials were forced to test it for rabies.</p>
```

As you may see in Chrome, this obscures the images. To fix that, we need to apply specific styles to image selection, with a lower opacity:

```css
::selection
{
  background: rgba(255, 127, 0, 0.996);
  color: white;
}

::-moz-selection
{
  background: #F80;
  color: white;
}

img::selection
{
  background: rgba(255, 127, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>The domestic cat is a small, usually furry, domesticated, and carnivorous mammal. They are often called a housecat when kept as an indoor pet, or simply a cat when there is no need to distinguish them from other felids and felines. Cats are often valued by humans for companionship.</p>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/75/300">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/300">
<p>A Melvin, Michigan woman was brutally attacked by a stray cat and shocking footage of the mauling has already gained a million views on YouTube.</p>
<p>The woman, who identified herself to reporters only as Maxx, endured the horrific attack November 30 but only recently realized it had been caught on her home surveillance camera.</p>
<p>The attack left her face swollen and infected and the cat named Buddy dead as officials were forced to test it for rabies.</p>
```

In Firefox, there is no way to override the blue selection color on images, it seems.