# CSS selection color behaving strangely on Chrome

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the selection color of my website using the CSS  `::selection` pseudoelement.

As seen in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3gfR/3/), the text is supposed to have a totally black background color when being selected. On Firefox, this is the case.

However, on Chrome, the color is *not absolutely black.* Chrome seems to be fiddling with my colors.

You can see this if you [leave the text black while selecting](http://jsfiddle.net/a3gfR/4/): on Firefox, it becomes invisible, while on Chrome you can still see it.

I've noticed this effect on other background colors that I was using: They were always a bit off on Chrome. It seems to me like a bit of red was added.

How can I get the true colors that I want on Chrome?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 ::selection behaves differently in FF & Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224445/css3-selection-behaves-differently-in-ff-chrome)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Possibly to prevent exactly what you are trying to do, it seems like Chrome will change the opacity of the background color of the selection if it's 1.  You can cheat this by setting the opacity very close to 1 like (`background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.99)`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/a3gfR/5/

Comment: This will disrupt selecting images. The image will be covered, but it should be slightly visible.

Comment: @rvighne Come to think of it, "selecting images" is a bit of an edge case.

Answer (score 4):

**When you are** using the suggestion above **Firefox** still shows a **light blue** color on **images** when you select it.

I could get rid of it by the following code:

```
img {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

The images are now ignored by selection.

**So by applying** this code I could get a more **uniform** look on all browsers.

```
*::selection {
    /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.99); /* black */
    color: #ffffff; /* white */
}

*::-moz-selection {
    /* Gecko Browsers */
    background: #000000; /* black */
    color: #ffffff; /* white */
}

img {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I've mentioned in a [separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29413950/124119), the closest value you could use is about `0.996`.

Also, give it a lower opacity for `img::selection` so images aren't completely obscured in Chrome.

Like so:

```
::-moz-selection { background: rgba(255, 127, 127, 1); }
::selection { background: rgba(255, 127, 127, 0.996); }
img::selection { background: rgba(255, 127, 127, 0.8); }
```