# why selection background color changes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flexbox

I applied `::selection background-color` but when I am checking using selection color using `digital color meter` it shows me different color

here is my code
https://jsbin.com/voketaqaxu/edit?html,css,js,output

```
::selection{
  background-color: rgb(78,106,65);

}
```

I applied `background-color: rgb(78,106,65);` on selection , but when I checked using digital color it show me this `rgb(42,70,31)` why ??

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS selection color behaving strangely on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970891/css-selection-color-behaving-strangely-on-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly to prevent exactly what you are trying to do.

Looks like Chrome will change the background color opacity of the selection if it's 1. You can cheat this by setting the opacity very close to 1 e.g.

```
background-color: rgb(78,106,65, .99);
```

Comment: any better soloution

Comment: no other way in my opinion, since it is based on the chrome to update the opacity.

Comment: checking in firefox