# Webkit : Css text selection styling can not make background white?

Tags: css, webkit, selection, styling

So text selection was made stylable trough the ::selection pseudo element in order to override the browser's default selection color. But to me, it seems that white as a selection background color is forbidden in favor of a greyish, opaque color.

```css
::selection      { color: black;  background: white; }
::-moz-selection { color: black;  background: white; }

body {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
So selecting me is supposed to invert the text and background colors. But the selected text background color is not white, but grey.
```

Why does this **not** create a perfectly white background ? Instead, it shows a grey background (#989898)

[image: Css selection does not accept white background]

Also see this snippet on https://jsfiddle.net/duk3/hzodm1sh/

Comment: Do you get this result in what browsers?

Comment: This happens in Chrome and Safari - still happening with the current versions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok so following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224445/css3-selection-behaves-differently-in-ff-chrome/7224621#7224621) I found the answer :

> For some reason Chrome forces it to be semi-transparent. However, you
>   can get around this by setting the background using rgba. I have set
>   the alpha value to be just 0.01 less than 1.

```css
::selection { color: black;  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.996);
; }

body {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
Selecting me DOES invert the text and background colors. Well, almost, but it looks like perfect white.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a browser specific problem.

Try this:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ko7ype05/2/)

```css
::selection {
    color: black;
    background: white;
}
body {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
::-moz-selection {
    color: black;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
So selecting me is supposed to invert the text and background colors.
```

Here is the result in a print:

[image: ...]

Comment: You're linking to a red background color selection example. I see it red also, my question concerns the white color specifically

Comment: Corrected @Romainpetit

Comment: Ok I edited the moz prefixed property, so we are using the same code now. Do you see real white or grey as selection background ?

Comment: When selected, I see black letters over a white background. I'll add a print to the answer

Comment: Thanks chaipa, so this must indeed be browser of environnement specific. I'm going to dig into this

Comment: @Romainpetit, sometimes we forget this: have you refreshed the page so it loads the new styles? Maybe it's reading the cached ones, without the moz prefixed property

Comment: No, thanks for caring. I've been testing in latest chrome and safari with cache cleared

Comment: This doesn't work on Webkit, which was specified in the question. Please don't post answers that don't work.