# Two browsers showing two different text highlight colours

Tags: html, css

I'm just customising parts of my website and decided to change the highlighting colour. In Brave Browser (Chromium based) the colour was viewed as intended but I then checked on Safari where the colour looks different.

This is the code snippet in my CSS:

```
::selection {
    color: black;
    background-color: #aaaaff;
}
::-moz-selection {
    color: black;
    background-color: #aaaaff;
}
```

Pictures are provided detailing the differences.

Brave Browser (correct)

[image: Brave Browser (correct)]

Safari

[image: Safari]

Does anybody know why this is happening and how to fix it so the highlight colour appears the same on all browsers?

Comment: I believe to make selection colors work consistently in all browsers you need to use a slight opacity to your color. Something like `rgba(100, 100, 255, 0.9)`

Comment: Ironically, Chromium used to have this issue [10 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224445/css3-selection-behaves-differently-in-ff-chrome) - but that was before the Blink fork happened. Not saying that is the reason why, though. But surprised to see this in Safari considering ::selection's behavior is now well-defined in css-pseudo-4. My guess is Safari is incorrectly applying this effect to highlighted text when the spec says it should only apply to highlighted replaced elements (such as images).

Comment: @Dominik: Yeah, 0.99 works as well. See the question I just linked to.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their answers. @BoltClock Is this solution (to define an opacity < 1) used as standard or is my situation a unique occurrence and usually not needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work in Safari Browser, you need to add a slight opacity. Instead of hex code, you can add rgba or hsla. It works fine, i checked it in Safari! It doesn't work if you set opacity 100%, but it works fine with 99%.

RGBA Colors:

```
::selection {
  color: black;  
  background-color: rgb(168 168 255 / 99%);
}
::-moz-selection {
  color: black;  
  background-color: rgb(168 168 255 / 99%);
}
```

HSLA Colors:

```
::selection {
  color: black;
  background-color: hsl(240deg 100% 83% / 99%);
}
::-moz-selection {
  color: black;
  background-color: hsl(240deg 100% 83% / 99%);
}
```